# Ошибка отсутствия ключа в словаре KeyError при разборе веб-страницы

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

При завершении парсинга и сохранении в csv выдается ошибка `KeyError: 'name1'`

В чем может быть проблема?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import requests
import csv

Base_URL = 'http://santehnika-online.ru/mebel_dlja_vannoj_komnaty/'

def get_html(url):
    responce = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return responce.read()

def get_page_count(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    paggination = soup.find('div', class_='paginator')
    return int(paggination.find_all('a')[-2].text)

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    links = []
    dlink = []
    vidacha = soup.find('div', class_='vidacha')
    for link in vidacha.find_all('a'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
    dlink = links[::3]
    i = 0
    string = "http://santehnika-online.ru"
    for tovar in dlink:
        dlink[i] = str(string) + str(tovar)
        i = i + 1      
    c = 0
    param = []
    spisok = []
    spisok2 = []
    for http in dlink:
        dlink[c] = http
        data = get_html(http)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
        row = soup.find('div', class_='zebragroup1 chars vklad')
        for table in row.findAll('ul')[0:]:
            colls = table.findAll('div')
            for i in colls:
                param.append({'name': i.text.split()})
            colls2 = table.findAll('span')
            for col in colls2:
                param.append({'name1': col.text.split()})
            param.append({'name2': soup.find('h1').text.split()})
    c = c + 1
    return param

def save(param, path):         
    with open(path, 'w', encoding='utf8', errors='replace') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(('Название',  'Описание', 'Наименование'))
        for parametr in param:
            writer.writerow((parametr['name'], 
                             ', '.join(parametr['name1']), 
                             parametr['name2']))

def main():
    page_count = get_page_count(get_html(Base_URL))

    print('Всего найдено страниц: %d' % page_count)

    param = []
    for page in range(1, 200):
        print('Парсинг %d%%' % (page / page_count * 100))
        param.extend(parse(get_html(Base_URL + '?PAGEN_1=%d' % page)))
    for parametr in param:
        print(parametr)

    save(param, 'paras.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Очевидно, что код падает, когда Вы пытаетесь достать значение по ключу `name1` в строке `', '.join(parametr['name1'])`, поскольку не может его найти в словаре. Попробуйте пройтись дебаггером, или просто распечатать переменную `parameter` в цикле, и посмотрите, что в ней хранится.

Comment: @soon Я тоже так думал, но если оставить один из 3х параметров, например тот же самый 'name1' например 'writer.writerow((parametr['name1']))' все парсится и сохраняется нормально. Возможно где-то синтаксическая ошибка, не могу понять где?

Comment: Поставьте print(parametr) в цикле над writer'ом да гляньте, что отпечатает перед ошибкой

Comment: Похоже я почти разобрался, после строчки 'for parametr in param:' в переменную 'parametr' заноситься только один ключ из всего списка, конечно же самый первый, соответственно это и вызывает исключение при попытке записать. Тогда возникает другой вопрос, как сделать так чтобы в переменную заносилось сразу 3 ключа.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ниже приведён код разбора страниц без обработки ошибок.

То, на что следует обратить внимание, указано в комментариях под литерами **NB**, в основном они касаются техники разбора страниц.

```
import requests
from requests.compat import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_soup(url):
    """Возвращает объект BeautifulSoup из HTML по указанному URL."""
    # NB: если requests уже импортирован, необходимость 
    # в прямом обращении к urllib для данной задачи отсутствует.
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

def get_items_from_url(url):
    """Этот код пришёл на смену parse() из вопроса."""

    soup = get_soup(url)

    # NB: set используется, чтобы избежать дублей ссылок.
    # NB: Для навигации по дереву супа используются селекторы css
    # (метод select).
    links = set(link.get('href') for link in soup.select('.vidacha a'))
    items_data = {}  # Здесь будут результаты разбора страницы.

    def get_text(element, selector):
        """Вспомогательная функция, чтобы выбирать текст 
        первого элемента из тех, что найдены в базовом элементе
        при помощи css селектора.

        """
        return element.select(selector)[0].text.strip()

    for link in links:
        # NB: Искомые ссылки начинаются с /product,
        # остальное нас не интересует.
        if not link.startswith('/product'):
            continue

        # NB: Абсолютный URL страницы с товаром получаем
        # из базового URL.
        target_url = urljoin(url, link)
        soup = get_soup(target_url)

        # NB: Для заданного товара формируем запись 
        # в словаре результатов. Ключами словаря будут
        # являться URL станиц.
        item_data = items_data.setdefault(target_url, {
            'title': get_text(soup, '.zagl'),
            'params': {}  # Сюда будут помещаться параметры товара.
        })

        for param_row in soup.select('.props_group li'):
            # Собираем параметры товара в словарь,
            # где ключ - имя параметра, а значение - его значение %).
            name = get_text(param_row, '.name')
            value = get_text(param_row, '.value')
            item_data['params'][name] = value

    return items_data
```

При сохранении в csv остаётся только пройти по полученной при помощи функции структуре данных.

Comment: Никак не получается разобрать структуру вложенных словарей. Нашел функцию key(), но она возвращает только уникальные значения. Пробую сохраниться такой конструкцией: –                    'for name in item_data['params']:
  writer.writerow(item_data['params'][name])', но сохраняються не все данные, хотя если писать: 'print(item_data['params'][name])', то выводяться все данные. @idle sign

Comment: @VasiliyKuramshin Сначала нужно определиться со структурой csv: какие в нём колонки будут. writer.writerow() ожидает последовательность, то есть, например, можно попробовать так, чтобы вывести значения всех параметров: writer.writerow(item_data['params'].values()).

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, у вас проблема в том, как вы составляете список `param` в функции `parse`.

В цикле `for table in row.findAll('ul')[0:]:` вы добавляете словари в список `param`, притом сначала добавляете словари только с одним ключом `'name'`:

```
for i in colls:
    param.append({'name': i.text.split()})
```

После этого добавляете словари с ключом `'name1'`:

```
for col in colls2:
    param.append({'name1': col.text.split()})
```

И уже после этого один словарь с ключом `'name2'`:

```
param.append({'name2': soup.find('h1').text.split()})
```

Таким образом, при попытке сохранить содержимое списка, при обращении к первому элементу этого списка (а это словарь с одним ключом `'name'`), возникает ошибка отсутствия ключа `'name1'`.